# find and select option from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Check the code below. There you will find two tables. Each table first `<th>` contains the main category name and under that all of sub category name.

My goal is when I click on Main category text the select category option will automatically select that category and when I click on subcategory text it will just copy the sub category text and paste to search box.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".table").each(function() {
    $(this).find('tr').slice(7).hide();
  });
  $(".expendbtn").html("More");
  $(document).on("click", '.expendbtn', function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "More") {
      $(this).prev(".table").find("tr").show();
      $(this).html("Less");
    } else {
      $(this).prev(".table").find('tr').slice(7).hide();
      $(this).html("More");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control txtSearch" id="searchString" type="text" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default btnGo" id="searchButton" type="button">Search</button>
          </span>

  </div>
  <br/>

  <select class="form-control" id="selectMainCategory">
               <option selected="selected" value="">Select Category</option>
                   <option value="20081">Antiques</option>
                   <option value="550">Art</option>
                   <option value="2984">Baby</option>
                   <option value="267">Books</option>
                   <option value="12576">Business &amp; Industrial</option>
                   <option value="625">Cameras &amp; Photo</option>
                   <option value="15032">Cell Phones &amp; Accessories</option>
                   <option value="11450">Clothing, Shoes &amp; Accessories</option>
                   <option value="11116">Coins &amp; Paper Money</option>
                   <option value="1">Collectibles</option>
                   <option value="58058">Computers/Tablets &amp; Networking</option>
                   <option value="293">Consumer Electronics</option>
                   <option value="14339">Crafts</option>
                   <option value="237">Dolls &amp; Bears</option>
                   <option value="11232">DVDs &amp; Movies</option>
                   <option value="45100">Entertainment Memorabilia</option>
                   <option value="172008">Gift Cards &amp; Coupons</option>
                   <option value="26395">Health &amp; Beauty</option>
                   <option value="11700">Home &amp; Garden</option>
                   <option value="281">Jewelry &amp; Watches</option>
                   <option value="11233">Music</option>
                   <option value="619">Musical Instruments &amp; Gear</option>
                   <option value="1281">Pet Supplies</option>
                   <option value="870">Pottery &amp; Glass</option>
                   <option value="10542">Real Estate</option>
                   <option value="316">Specialty Services</option>
                   <option value="888">Sporting Goods</option>
                   <option value="64482">Sports Mem, Cards &amp; Fan Shop</option>
                   <option value="260">Stamps</option>
                   <option value="1305">Tickets &amp; Experiences</option>
                   <option value="220">Toys &amp; Hobbies</option>
                   <option value="3252">Travel</option>
                   <option value="1249">Video Games &amp; Consoles</option>
                   <option value="99">Everything Else</option>
           </select>
  <br/>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
          <th>
            <h4>Business &amp; Industrial</h4>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Adhesives, Sealants &amp; Tapes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Agriculture &amp; Forestry</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Automation, Motors &amp; Drives</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cleaning &amp; Janitorial Supplies</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Construction</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Electrical &amp; Test Equipment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Facility Maintenance &amp; Safety</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Fasteners &amp; Hardware</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Fuel &amp; Energy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Healthcare, Lab &amp; Life Science</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Heavy Equipment</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Heavy Equipment Attachments</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Heavy Equipment Parts &amp; Accs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>HVAC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Hydraulics, Pneumatics &amp; Pumps</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Light Equipment &amp; Tools</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Manufacturing &amp; Metalworking</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Material Handling</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Office</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Printing &amp; Graphic Arts</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Restaurant &amp; Catering</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Retail &amp; Services</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Websites &amp; Businesses for Sale</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Other Business &amp; Industrial</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>

    <button class="btn btn-info expendbtn" type="button">More</button>
  </div>


  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <table class="table table-striped jambo_table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
          <th>
            <h4>Cameras &amp; Photo</h4>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Binoculars &amp; Telescopes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Camcorders</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Camera &amp; Photo Accessories</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Camera Drones</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Camera Drone Parts &amp; Accs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Camera Manuals &amp; Guides</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Digital Cameras</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Digital Photo Frames</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Film Photography</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Flashes &amp; Flash Accessories</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Lenses &amp; Filters</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Lighting &amp; Studio</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Replacement Parts &amp; Tools</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Tripods &amp; Supports</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Video Production &amp; Editing</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Vintage Movie &amp; Photography</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Wholesale Lots</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none;">
          <td>Other Cameras &amp; Photo</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>

    <button class="btn btn-info expendbtn" type="button">More</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but it looks like you haven't really *tried*. You're trying to use stackoverflow as a free codewriting service.

Comment: Everything is possible with JavaScript (at least within the confines of the browser).

Comment: I have searched for this kind of autoselect function in jquery but not found any function actually

Comment: No that is because you have to write that by yourself. Your project is unique and requires tailor made code. You can however draw inspiration from other question here at SO.

Comment: Please provide some hints about paste function atleast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will select the option with the header text and copy the td text as the search string.

```
        $('th').on('click',  function () {
            var txt =$.trim( $(this).text());
            console.log(txt);
            $("#selectMainCategory option").each(function () {
                    if ( $.trim($(this).text()) === txt) {
                        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
                        return;
                    }
            });
        });

        $('td').on('click',  function () {
            var txt =$.trim( $(this).text());
            console.log(txt); 
            $("#searchString").val(txt);

        });
```